# How to address contrast between current and past employment?

Tags: interviewing, resume, career-development, work-experience

This is during interviews.

I'm presently employed and it's not a good fit for various reasons. I'd like to work at something more interesting, challenging, with project work as time goes on versus always doing grunt work (e.g. set up computers) or help desk calls, I just don't want to do only grunt work all the time.

I was outsourced from my previous job after 18+ years, then right after unemployment ended I had to take the first only job that was offered, the one I'm in now.

I'm trying to figure out how to explain the differences between the two positions, e.g. why the change of jobs, why significantly fewer lines on my resume for the current job, etc.

My current job looks really small/insignificant compared to my previous job, how to deal with this without being negative?? I'm not doing very much in my new job that I didn't already do in my previous job.

I have the current gig on my resume because I am indeed employed, which hopefully is still a good thing while seeking employment??

I did say in an interview the honest response that I was outsourced, unemployment ended and I took this position to become employed for a new different experience, and I have no idea how that was received, other than they didn't hire me.

Most of my cover letter (vs. resume) refers to work I did in my previous job, there's a lot more to talk about, current gig not so much.

Thank you, Tom

Comment: What was your previous job?

Comment: Do you think that you are **under-employed** now because your current job does not allow you to realize all your potentials and skills ?

Comment: If the current job is for a short amount of time, just leave it off.

Answer (score 8):

I think you should explain it exactly like that

We all had to get a survival job once or twice, and in my opinion, honesty is the best policy

Answer (score 3):

Especially if you don't want a similar job again be honest and upfront about it. It's going to get you declined from the jobs that are looking for someone to do more grunt work, and it's going to be a positive for the jobs that want you to step up beyond the grunt work. Unless you're desperate there's almost never a reason to not just be honest and upfront about the whole deal. You might wanna add that you didn't think it would be so bad when you started the job so you didn't only take the job as an intermediate out of desperation, but beyond that you're good to go. There's no reason ambition to have more complex or bigger tasks would be viewed negatively unless they had more grunt work for you in mind.

Just don't trashtalk your current employer and you're set.

Comment: I'd also add that you can use your cover letter/interview (if asked/prompted) to talk about the aspects of your current job that are still applicable/useful for the kind of work you're looking for, even if it's in a different field or a lower level of work/responsibility than the kinds of jobs you're now looking for. For instance, what skills have you gained or do you use in your current job that would be relevant to the job you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Stick to the simplest facts and keep it simple, if they ask answer in simplest terms.

If it doesn't highlight you in a positive way there's no point waffling on about it unnecessarily.